# Using readv(), writev() and poll() from C++

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, select

There is a [multiplayer card game](http://preferans.de) which I had first programmed as a non-forking socket server in C (using poll() call).

Then it was too difficult for me to add new features and I've switched to Perl (using IO::Poll module).

As Perl doesn't support readv()/writev(), requires more memory/CPU and also isn't very commercial (I'd like to sell my game later), I would like to port my server back to C++ in future - once my features stabilize. (C++ this time because there are few objects in my server).

**Could anyone please supply me with an example, how to use readv(), writev() and poll() or select() under C++?** I know how to use those under Perl and C, but I haven't found any examples for C++ yet.

My environment: I'm using OpenBSD with its gcc/g++ and I'd like my server to run under Linux as well. I'd prefer not to use any unusual libraries (like libevent?) unless they work under Windows too - because maybe in the future I want to port my server to Windows too (for that I think I'll have to switch back from poll() to select() and add few Winsock functions?).

Please let me add that I like both Perl and C and I respect C++ very much, so this question is not about which language or OS is better. My question is: how to use poll() with C++

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions `readv()`, `writev()`, and `poll()` work the same way in C++ as they do in C.

Comment: There isn't any difference between the C functions and the C++ functions in this case.  You'll often find that's the case (not always) but very often.

Answer (score 3):

C++ handles them exactly the same as C -- Here's a tutorial to get you [started](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).

However, since you're writing it in C++, I'd strongly advise you to take a look at the powerful alternatives, like the [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) framework. Believe me, you'll save a lot of time and nerves in implementing a server using Asio.